# Using Argparse in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I just have a quick question. In the simple module import sys, you can identify an argument's position like so:

```
    if len(sys.argv)==2:
       csvFile = sys.argv[1]
```

this lets you store the second argument inputted by the user at the command line into the variable csvFile. I was just wondering how you would do this using argparse module because when i tried using `if len(sys.argv)==2` using argparse it gave me an error: `'module' has no attribute 'args'`.

Comment: That exception has **nothing** to do with `len(sys.argv)`, but rather looks like you made a typo: `len(sys.args)` waould throw that exception, for example.

Comment: How did you use `argparse`?

Comment: How i want to use is it is basically write something like -x file.csv and then it turns the file into a xml. To do this i need the to find the position of the file.csv, so in this case, csvFile = sys.argv[1] which means that the file.csv is saved in the variable csvFile

Comment: "How I want to use it" and "How I actually tried to use it" are two different things. When you claim that your code produces an error, it's a good idea to show the exact code that produced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **argparse** you shouldn't need to worry about position of arguments, let the module do the work for you

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x')
```

Now, to simulate passing *-x filename* as part of the command line, e.g.

```
parser.parse_args(['-x','filename'])
```

Which results in `Namespace(x='filename')`

If the `-x` argument doesn't appear, as below:

parser.parse_args([])

It will result in `Namespace(x=None)`

See [argparse module documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for more details on using this powerful library.